# gradle task which works with files

Tags: gradle

I am trying to write `task` that works with files, based on `gradle-watch-plugin`. (Though it does not now. It supposed to run when I start `threadWatch` task I presume)

However I don't get how to pass and get passed filenames inside task.

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'
apply plugin: 'groovy'
apply plugin: 'com.bluepapa32.watch'

watch {
    rules {
        files fileTree(dir: '/src/main/resources', include: '*.xls')
        tasks 'validateRules'
    }
}

....

dependencies {
    compile "org.codehaus.groovy:groovy-all:2.0.5"

    compile ("org.drools:drools-core:${droolsVersion}")
    compile ("org.drools:drools-compiler:${droolsVersion}")
    compile ("org.drools:drools-decisiontables:${droolsVersion}")
}

import org.drools.builder.*
import org.drools.io.ResourceFactory

task validateRules(type: DefaultTask) {

    ext.ruleValidator = { 
        xls_file_name ->
            try {
                def tConfig = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newDecisionTableConfiguration().with {
                    tConfig.inputType = DecisionTableInputType.XLS
                    def builder = KnowledgeBuilderFactory.newKnowledgeBuilder().with {
                        builder.add(
                            ResourceFactory.newInputStreamResource(new FileInputStream(xls_file_name)),
                            ResourceType.DTABLE,
                            tConfig
                        )
                        if (builder.hasErrors()) {
                            println 'Invalid ${xls_file_name} rule table!'
                        }
                    }
                    table.add rFactory
                }
            } catch (exc) {
                println exc.getMessage()
            }
    }

    doLast {
        ruleValidator()
    }
}

task watchThread() << {
    Thread.start {
        project.tasks.watch.execute()
    }
}
```

According to [Gradle Watch Plugin](https://github.com/bluepapa32/gradle-watch-plugin) I need to define `watch` configuration with needed task and file list.

However it did not described how task should look like and how pass parameters there -> So I created task, based on `DefaultTask` , which needs to acquire file list.

However I don't know to get it there because I don't understand how `watch` plugin is passing there. At all.

Comment: Could you be more precise? What's the exact problem? And where is that place in the code?

Comment: @Opal It's in the whole code. I have a task on the bottom and `watch` configuration in the top. It somehow passes files to task, however I don't get how and whether I am doing it correct.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, since Gradle 2.5 there is a continuous build mode (-t on command-line), which means you can forego the use of the watch plugin in most cases. You should consider upgrading your build to at least 2.5 if it is possible.

Now as to the code itself, there is a couple of things you can do better.

[1] You seem to have mixed task configuration with task action.

```
task ValidateRules << {
    // Given that you are assuming a single XLS file you can do
    // (It will throw exception if there is more than one)
    def xls_file_name = inputs.files.singleFile

    // ... rest of your code inside the try block can follow here
    // (I would not catch the exception, but rather let Gradle handle it)
}
```

[2] Now configure your custom task to act upon a change in inputs

```
ValidateRules {
  inputs.files fileTree(dir: '/src/main/resources', include: '*.xls')
}
```

Comment: Well I assume that one file is changed per time -> as soon as any file changed I want to run task. And I can't use 2.5 gradle - it's a little part of huge old application. We've just recently migrated to 2.4.